# Why is Canvas used more than JPanel for making games in Java?

Tags: java

I saw many Ludum Dare games, which are written in Java (using its standard library). I checked the code of one or two of them and the thing that I saw is in their Game `class`, they extend `Canvas`.

So my question is why would they extend `Canvas`, not `JPanel`?

Comment: I believe, when using a Canvas, you can use a custom BufferedStrategy instead of the JPanels default doubleBufferStrategy

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the actual code, it's difficult to say.  However, I would guess that they are using both Canvas and JPanel somewhere (or at least some form of JPanel, e.g. JFrame or Applet etc..) and simply extending the game class from Canvas to make it more portable, i.e. so it can be added to a JPanel (or whatever) later.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question. I developed a game with JPanel in Linux and at the end discovered that it was not functioning in Windows (`getBufferStrategy null`). Switching to canvas fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the API

### [Canvas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) extends [Component](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html)

**Component:**

> A component is an object having a graphical representation that can be displayed on the screen and that can interact with the user.

**Canvas**

> A Canvas component represents a blank rectangular area of the screen onto which the application can draw or from which the application can trap input events from the user.

### [JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) extends JComponent

**JComponent**

> The base class for all *Swing components* except top-level containers.

**JLabel**

> JPanel is a generic lightweight container.

### summary

if you do not implement a [Swing Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) then you forgo JComponents and stick with the basic Components.